# Change Background in Android UI Table Library(thiagolocatelli)

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to find a way to change the background of the Android Library like: 
     1.row darkgrey;
     2. row grey; 3. row darkgrey; 4.row grey etc.

But it did not work.

**I tried it with:**

```
 if(mIndexController%2 ==1){
            itemContainer.setBackgroundColor(R.color.grey);
            viewsContainer.setBackgroundColor(R.color.grey);
        }
        else{

            itemContainer.setBackgroundColor(R.color.darkgrey);
            viewsContainer.setBackgroundColor(R.color.darkgrey);
        }
```

In the Library UITableView Activity, But its not working.

Could someone help me?

Here is the Library:
https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview

I want the ListView to look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls5bG.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own view and then apply the background color you want each row to have and then add it as a custom view. If you want different colors for odd/even rows thats the best approach right now. I am in process of updating this library, there will be a function to return the childs of the uitableview so you can iterate among them and set the background color per row.

Comment: just create your own row xml and apply the colors you need before adding it to the UITableView. You can copy any of the list_item_*.xml from https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview/tree/master/android-uitableview/res/layout and use it in our own project and then just add to the table view

Answer (score 3):

In fact `viewsContainer.setBackgroundColor(R.color.grey);` does nothing.

You should correct it like this:

```
 viewsContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
```

Answer (score 0):

I this you should try this.

```
itemContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
```

Comment: I think* you should try this.